# Service Component object is not loaded in Spring Batch processor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

Service Component object is not loaded in Spring Batch processor.But which is working fine with Spring Testing.Please help me to find the solution for this.

```
public class PersonJobProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Person,Person> {

    @Autowired
    PersonService service;

    @Override
    public Person process(final Person person) throws Exception {
    //user service variable here
    }
    }
Error Message:-
Action:Consider defining a bean of type 'PersonService' in your configuration.
```

Below configuration is working fine

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class PersonServiceTest {

@Autowired
PersonService service;  

public void testmethod(){
  service.method();// works without issues
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like missing SpringContext inside PersonJobProcessor. Did you add @Component on this class?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.